# control one sections height

Tags: html, css

I am making my own fishing website:) But I am really in doubt how to structure some of my sections. The pictures below shows how I would like this section. On that specifik section I have a 100% width. But if I set a height and padding on that sections, it affects all my other col-12. So how can I set a height, padding, margin on that specifik section?

**How I would like my page:**
[image: How I would like it]

**My Site:**
[image: My Site]

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Main & Nav -->
    <div class="main-header" role="main">
        <nav class="global-nav">
            <ul class="title-area">
                <li>sdf</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- Here is the section I would like to style -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12">
            <h2>Favorite Flies</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Flies -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
                <li><span class="filter active" data-filter="app card icon logo web">Rated</span></li>
                <li><span class="filter" data-filter="app">Sea</span></li>
                <li><span class="filter" data-filter="card">Lake</span></li>
                <li><span class="filter" data-filter="icon">Autaum</span></li>
                <li><span class="filter" data-filter="logo">Summer</span></li>
                <li><span class="filter" data-filter="web">Winter</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row  mar-b-30">
        <div id="portfoliolist">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="portfolio logo" data-cat="logo">
                <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="image-caption">
                            <a href="img/portfolios/logo/5.jpg" class="label magnefig label-info icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Zoom"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="blog-detail.html" class="label label-info icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Details"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>


                        </div>
                        <img src="img/fly/barbine.jpg" alt="" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio app" data-cat="app">
                <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="image-caption">
                            <a href="img/portfolios/app/3.jpg" class="label magnefig label-info icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Zoom"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="blog-detail.html" class="label label-info icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Details"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>


                        </div>
                        <img src="img/fly/black_dog.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    body {
        color: #797979;
        font-family: 'roboto'; 
        font-weight: 300;
        padding: 0px !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
        font-family: 'roboto'; 
        font-weight: 300;
        text-align: center;
    }
    a,
    a:hover,
    a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: none;
    }
    ::selection {
        background: #48cfad;
        color: #fff;
    }
    ::-moz-selection {
        background: #48cfad;
        color: #fff;
    }


        #map {
                width: 100%;
                height: 300px;
              }

        .global-nav {
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            height: 55px;
            background: #333;
        }
        .main-header {
            background: url(../img/bg_1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            height: 700px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        /* Rows */
        .row{
          margin-left:-15px;
          margin-right:-15px;
         }
        .row:after{
          content:'';
          display:block;
          clear:both
        }
        /* General properties of columns */
        .col{
          padding: 0rem;
          float:left; 
        }

        /* Column Definition */
        .col-1{
          width:8.33333333%
        }

        .col-2{
          width:16.66666667%
        }

        .col-3{
          width:25%
        }

        .col-4{
          width:33.33333333%
        }

        .col-5{
          width:14.666667%
        }

        .col-6{
          width:50%;
        }

        .col-7{
          width:58.33333333%
        }

        .col-8{
          width:66.6666667%
        }

        .col-9{
          width:75%
        }

        .col-10{
          width:83.33333333%
        }

        .col-11{
          width:91.6666666%
        }
        .col-12{
          width:100%;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more class or an id to the 'div' you want for which you want to set the height, padding and margin.

Then jump into your CSS and use the newly made class name or id to set the height, padding and margin.

Code :

```css
.colPadding {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-12 colPadding">
    <h2>Favorite Flies</h2> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. An example might help too:

<div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12 colPadding">
            <h2>Favorite Flies</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

and the CSS:

.colPadding{
  padding:20px;
}

Comment: Ah okay. I actually tought that it was not "good coding" when you made it responsive. But then I will just throw an id on it. Maybe I have to use the same height later on also, so I can call the same id then.

Comment: There is nothing like bad coding unless you are able to get the thing done without harming anything else.If you are working in a group then you must  add comments. 
don't forget to validate the answer if it's resolve your issue

Comment: I will remember that. I am always so scared of doing the coding not good enough. My friends says to me, "but if it is working, isnt it fine enough then.." Then you can always make the code better and nicer when with time when you learn more.. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: you are doing like this: col col-12 colPadding. It seems pretty smart. But why are you not using `id="colPadding" og class="colPadding"` ?

Comment: See its the same thing you could have gone with an id="colPadding" 
But I personally prefer to use classes(weather you use class or an id its more of a personal choice, using a class make my life easier when i use jquery). 
As far as using 

' class="colPadding" ' 

is concerned whats the point in writing a few extra letters when you have a short hand for it.

Comment: Cool thanks a lot. I didnt knew that you could do that. I will do the same thing like you :)